# Two browsers in the same Electron window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, electron

I'd like to have **one single Electron window**, split in two parts:

- the left part is a `BrowserWindow` loading https://gmail.com
- the right part is another `BrowserWindow` loading Gmail too, but I'd like these two browsers to be "independent", i.e. the cookies/LocalStorage/etc. should be independent (like if we have a normal Chrome window vs. a incognito window) ; thus allowing to have one Gmail account on left / another account connected on the right part
- some other UI buttons on top of the single Electron window.

This code works, but it creates 2 windows instead of one:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

app.once('ready', () => {
  let win = new BrowserWindow({show: false})
  win.once('show', () => { win.webContents.executeJavaScript('validateFlights()') })
  win.loadURL('https://www.gmail.com')
  win.show()

  let win2 = new BrowserWindow({show: false})
  win2.once('show', () => { win.webContents.executeJavaScript('validateFlights()') })
  win2.loadURL('https://www.gmail.com')
  win2.show()
})
```

**How to have them in one window?**

Comment: Why not use one single BrowserWindow and two iframe(s) ?

Comment: @Kornflexx I assume gmail might be serving frame-busting code. If you can find a way to work around that (might be possible in electron), then this is a valid solution.

Comment: May be its not possible, indirectly you want to run two app in same code. Every app have their own instance

Comment: @Kornflexx in fact it's more complex because I want that, after restarting the application, the left browser remains connected to the account / the right browser remains connected to the other account (each one with its cookies).

Comment: Another example: you want to create a "browser" with Electron (we've run full circle, that's right ;)), like https://github.com/wexond/wexond: we need to be able to display top UI buttons (to select tabs), and the actual browser area in the same window.

Comment: I think you are looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55344701/how-to-stop-electron-windows-sharing-cookies

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is [BrowserView](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-view)

From the docs:

> A `BrowserView` can be used to embed additional web content into a `BrowserWindow`. It is like a child window, except that it is positioned relative to its owning window. It is meant to be an alternative to the `webview` tag.

It looks like this is what you want, the views can render separate HTML pages and position them relatively inside the same browser window.

```
// In the main process.
const { BrowserView, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

let win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })
win.on('closed', () => {
  win = null
})

let view = new BrowserView({
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: false
  }
})
win.setBrowserView(view)
view.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300 })
view.webContents.loadURL('https://electronjs.org')
```

Comment: the problem with `BrowserView` is that its seemingly outside of the document flow. how do you embed a `BrowserView` similar to a `webview`?

Answer (score 14):

A little late, but to add two browsers within one window you have to use `BrowserWindow.addBrowserView` instead of `BrowserWindow.setBrowserView`. You'll get the following:

```
const { BrowserView, BrowserWindow, app } = require('electron')
function twoViews () {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })

  const view = new BrowserView()
  win.addBrowserView(view)
  view.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 300 })
  view.webContents.loadURL('https://electronjs.org')

  const secondView = new BrowserView()
  win.addBrowserView(secondView)
  secondView.setBounds({ x: 400, y: 0, width: 400, height: 300 })
  secondView.webContents.loadURL('https://electronjs.org')
  app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    win.removeBrowserView(secondView)
    win.removeBrowserView(view)
    app.quit()
  })
}

app.whenReady().then(twoViews)
```

Once you create two `BrowserView` objects, you just add them to the window. You'll also want to remove the views when tearing down the application. If you don't you might get a segmentation fault.