# How to stop Electron windows sharing cookies?

Tags: node.js, electron

I am creating multiple browser windows in an electron app however I do not want them to share cookies. This is how I am currently creating the windows,

```
function createWindow() {
    // Create the browser window.
    let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ minWidth: 660, minHeight: 400, width: 1208, height: 680 })
    // setInterval(() => sendStatus(0, 'FAIL'), 5000);
    // Emitted when the window is closed.
    return mainWindow;
}
```

However when multiple windows are open they share cookies between them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a `session` (or `partition`) for [`BrowserWindow`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions) instances

Browser windows in different sessions don't share cookies, so you just have to define different session for each of your windows. Like

```
let counter = 0

function createWindow() {
  let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      session: session.fromPartition(`${counter++}`)
    }
  })
  return mainWindow;
}
```

or any more sophisticated way.

Comment: the session will be in the memory right ? is there a way to destroy the session or not save them at all ?

Comment: thanks, you can do something similar to attach a session to a new BrowserWindow

Comment: @Dorian AFAIK you cannot, u can only pass session to webcontents at time of creation

Comment: @pergy I did and it works :) I already have `BrowserWindow`s sharing a session and wanted to have the same session in a new `BrowserWindow`

Comment: @Dorian well, yes, you can do that, in constructor you can use already used sessions (OP asked how to get rid of that) ;). I thought you want to assign a new session for an already created BW.